# rails activeadmin initialize command frozen

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I'm trying to use activeadmin, but when I try to execute the setup command, the terminal keeps frozen, with no output

Gemfile:
`gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'`

Setup command:
`rails generate active_admin:install`

Comment: What version of Rails do you use?

Comment: I'm using rails 4.1.8

Comment: I just created a blank rails app with the same setup, and the generator worked well. Maybe you can try again with --trace option?

Comment: its the same  https://www.dropbox.com/s/k3tvz4aweyflj94/Screenshot%202014-12-21%2012.11.19.png?dl=0

Comment: Sorry, rails command doesn't have --trace option. It does not help. Do you have Admin class? Maybe try `rails generate active_admin:install --skip-users` to skip that part for now.

Comment: You can try `bundle update activeadmin` to ensure you pull the latest changes from the master branch.

Comment: i've removed the project and started a new one, now when i run the command i get this message: ``` Warning: Running `gem pristine --all` to regenerate your installed gemspecs (and deleting then reinstalling your bundle if you use bundle --path) will improve the startup performance of Spring.``` (and the terminal keep frozen after this message)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67412/discussion-between-baxang-and-letz).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the `spring gem`.

I've removed the `spring gem` from the GemFile, and then it worked

Comment: @letz Can you clarify what exact problem was there and how has it been fixed?

Comment: @letz Thanks for the update. Now that explains how the issue was fixed. But still can't understand from the question where was `spring gem` initially. The answer doesn't look related to the question.

Comment: ` spring gem` is in the GemFile when you create a new rails app, and the propose of the gem is to speed up the development process:

```
Spring is a Rails application preloader. It speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background so you don't need to boot it every time you run a test, rake task or migration.
```

Maybe have some kind of incompatibility with that version of active admin

Answer (score 0):

After a chat, it turned out the generator command worked with spring turned off. The clue was when he stopped the command hung:

```
^C/Users/letz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/client/run.rb:54:in `gets': Interrupt 
from /Users/letz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/client/run.rb:54:in `verify_server_version' 
from /Users/letz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/client/run.rb:25:in `call' 
from /Users/letz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call' 
from /Users/letz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:23:in `call'
```